# How to show entries in Table_1 that have exactly n entries in Table_2?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm not entirely sure how to ask this question in a general way so I'll just ask the way its been presented to me. The two relevant tables are:

```
Manager (
    ID: integer, 
    LoginID: varchar(16), 
    Name: varchar(64), 
    Password: varchar(8), 
    Birthday: date, 
    Address: varchar(128), 
    Email: varchar(32), 
    PhoneNumber: char(10)
)  

ManagerCertificate (
    ManagerID: integer, -- Foreign key: ManagerID references Manager(ID) 
    CertificateId: integer, 
    Certificate: blob
)
```

Show the names and emails of every manager who has exactly 3 distinct certificates.

I've tried a few things but I keep failing.
Do I use a nested subquery, count operator maybe...

```
select M.Name, M.Email
from Manager M, ManagerCertificate MC
??? where MC.ManagerID = M.ID    ???
```

I'm looking to be pointed in the right direction. I might be over complicating this.

Thanks

Comment: You will need `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` and `COUNT (DISTINCT)`. And, please, use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `JOIN` with `COUNT` is one way to do this, grouping on the manager name and email and checking (using `HAVING`) that the manager has exactly 3 distinct certificates. Note that MySQL < 5.7 would allow you to group on M.ID but it is preferable to write queries that will still work on later versions). Also note that explicit `JOIN` syntax (with an `ON` clause) is preferred to the old-style comma joins.

```
SELECT M.Name, M.Email
FROM Manager M
JOIN ManagerCertificate MC ON MC.ManagerID = M.ID
GROUP BY M.Name, M.Email
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT MC.CertificateId) = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I can give you an answer in Oracle SQL which you can likely translate.

```
Select m.manager_id, m.manager_name  
from managers m, 
(select manager_id, count(*)
from certificates
group by manager_id
having count = 3) c
where m.manager_id = c.manager_id
```

Comment: You probably want a `COUNT(DISTINCT...)` here just in case a manager has received the same CertificateID multiple times. OP didn't specify, so it's not safe to assume the CertificateID is unique.

Comment: nice thought -- I imagined these were management certifications of some sort, so duplicates wouldn't occur.  However, I appreciate your contribution.

Comment: How do answers that use archaic `JOIN` syntax get upvoted?

Answer (score 1):

I like using a subquery and `COUNT(DISTINCT)` here.

```
SELECT 
    M.Name
    , M.Email
FROM Manager M
INNER JOIN ( 
            SELECT ManagerID 
            FROM ManagerCertificate MC 
            GROUP BY ManagerID 
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CertificateId) = 3 
            ) C 
    ON M.ManagerID = C.ManagerID;
```